# Access delegate protocol from Swift framework into Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, delegates

I've created the `Swift` framework and integrated into `ObjC` project.

Now, I want to pass/access delegate handler in `ObjC`.

Swift Framework contains `UIViewController` with close and submit button.

**ListViewController.swift** `SwiftFramework`

```
public protocol ListHandler {
    func submit(options: String)
    func close()
}

public class ListViewController: UIViewController {

    public var handler: ListHandler?

    @objc func dismiss(_ sender: UIButton) {
        handler?.close()
    }

    @objc func submit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        handler?.submit(options: "Done")
    }
}
```

Created  **MyApp-Bridginh-Header.h**
And **SwiftWrapper.swift** to show `ListViewController`

```
import SwiftFramework

@objc public class SwiftWrapper: NSObject {

    @objc public var controller: ListViewController?

    override init() {
        print("Working")
    }

    @objc public func showListScreen() -> UIViewController {

        self.controller = ListViewController(title: "List")

        /*
          IMPORTANT: How I can pass this to ObjC called controller?
        */
        // self.controller?.handler =
        return self.controller!
    }
}
```

Finally in objC view controller, able to show List screen but can't pass delegate and handle submit/close button actions.

**ProductListViewController.m**

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"

SwiftWrapper *wrapper = [[SwiftWrapper  alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[wrapper showListScreen]];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How to access here?

Example project repository:
Swift Framework: https://github.com/harshal-wani/SwiftListFramework
ObjC project: https://github.com/harshal-wani/SwiftFrameworkDelegateExample

Appreciate your help and suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: why your protocol is not `@objc`? also where are you trying to access this delegate? I can't see it in your code

Comment: You cant add @objc to delegate property as its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper class do the work for you. Let's add all the functions in wrapper class which can manage the internal framework class features.

After viewing your source code, you required to do lot of changes in all the classes. Let's start with `ListViewController`.

1. Provide protocol class type to protocol definition. You can use `NSObject`.

So your protocol will be like:

```
public protocol ListHandler: NSObject {
    func submit(options: String)
    func close()
}
```

2. `SwiftWrapper` class: Using this class you can not directly pass `handler` to Objective-C classes, so you need to create one delegate or protocol in this class which can communicate with the Objective-C classes.

So create one delegate in this class:

```
@objc protocol SwiftWrapperDelgate {
    func submit(options: String)
    func close()
}
```

Now, the `protocol` methods of `ListViewController` must be declared in this class so that we can pass it to Objective-C from here. Create an `extension` to listen for the protocol methods.

```
extension SwiftWrapper : ListHandler {
    public func submit(options: String) {
        self.delegate?.submit(options: options)
    }

    public func close() {
        self.delegate?.close()
    }
}
```

And, don't forgot to assign delegate in `showListscreen()` function otherwise this method won't invoke.

```
@objc public func showListscreen() -> UIViewController {
    self.controller = ListViewController(title: "Demo List")
    self.controller?.handler = self
    return self.controller!
}
```

3. Now in Objective-C `ViewController.m` file assign delegate of `SwiftWrapper` class

   ```
   @interface ViewController () <SwiftWrapperDelgate>

   @property (nonatomic, strong) SwiftWrapper *wrapper;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) ListViewController *controller;

   @end
   ```

Here I have created global variables for `SwiftWrapper` & `ListViewController`

In `viewDidLoad()` create object of `SwiftWrapper` class and assign it's delegate to `self`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.wrapper = [SwiftWrapper new];
    self.wrapper.delegate = self;
}
```

And, finally create delegate methods which will be called on action of `ListViewController` class.

```
- (void)submitWithOptions:(NSString *)options {
    NSLog(@"Submit button tapped");
}

- (void) close {
    NSLog(@"Close button tapped");
}
```

Follow these steps to achieve your requirement.

Comment: seems can't catch the submit/close action when user click in Objc class? how we can do?

Comment: Uploaded example repository of both. Please check

Comment: works perfectly! Actually, I was trying to avoid double delegate creation but seems can't work.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from comments, you should make protocol to work with objective-c 
Start by:

```
@objc public protocol ListHandler {
    func submit(options: String)
    func close()
}
```

Then you will be able to make

```
@objc public var handler: ListHandler?
```

Comment: showing error: Method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C

Comment: Uploaded example repository of both. Please check

Comment: @HarshalWani in your example you still did not add @objc to `protocol ListHandler`, please use our advices and then try to use your code

Comment: as I answered before in a comment, already tried.
also in demo proj showing error: Use of undeclared type 'ListHandler'

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong. would appreciate your help to please try to make changes in repos, thanks

Comment: @HarshalWani Line number 11 in this file https://github.com/harshal-wani/SwiftListFramework/blob/master/SwiftListFramework/ListViewController.swift I can't see any `@objc` please use our advices

Comment: I think you are not getting my comment, I already tried your solution in local repo still didn't work. That's why I asked you to try and if works, please commit or suggest other way. Thanks for your efforts :)